# Does wubi need separate partition? Can I manually allocate space for my home folder?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, wubi

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04, but there are some programs like AutoCAD, SolidWorks and Comsol Multyphysics that can run only on a Windows system.

I decided to reinstall my laptop, so I will install first Windows XP and then Ubuntu 12.04 again.

1. While installing Windows - do I have to make 2 partitions (one for XP and another for Ubuntu) or at the next step, when I'm going to install Ubuntu, I can do it?
2. If I'm installing Ubuntu with Wubi, can I decide how much space will be my home folder, or it's doing everything automatically?

Comment: Just a suggestion, why not install Ubuntu, and Windows in a Virtual Machine?

Comment: You can also try [Wine](http://www.winehq.org).

Comment: Wine?! That's for running Windows apps in Ubuntu... He's trying to install Ubuntu in a Windows PC!

Comment: as espectall123 said Wine has nothing to do with an ubuntu installation.

Comment: To @espectalll123 - Now I'm with Ubuntu 12.04 but with the old kernel ... I want to reinstall the whole system, because I don't know how to compile the new one ;)
And I decided to get Windows only because I can't run programs like these, which I need for my studying ...
But I like Ubuntu and I'll have 2 OS until I acquire more knowledge and make all programs which I need working at linux ;)

Comment: To @Mitch - I don't know how to do it yet ... I'm still a novice ;)

Comment: To @EmersonHsieh - I was searching at WineHQ for these programs, but there were quite anything ...

Comment: @espectalll123 Mitch said to try Windows in a VM and I suggested the OP to try Wine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create 2 partitions when you install Windows XP if you want, but it is also possible to do it as you install Ubuntu afterwards, also the Ubuntu installer is more graphical therefore I think it is much easier to use so I would recommend doing as you install Ubuntu.

You can select how much space is used by the whole of Ubuntu when you install with wubi, although you cannot decide how much space is used specifically by the home folder (but I believe you wanted to decide how much space the whole of Ubuntu uses anyway).

I would recommend installing Ubuntu via a live CD/DVD/USB rather than using wubi if your are comfortable doing so as wubi is known to (although rarely) cause problems.

Hope this helps.

P.S. This answer may be worded badly with mistakes as I have just woken up so an edit would be much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1):

1. No, Ubuntu is installed *in a file* inside the Windows partition. One of the reasons for this is that it minimizes the risk that the Windows system will be damaged in any way by installing or using the Wubi system.
2. Yes, you can decide how much HD you want for Ubuntu... *but* there's a limit which forces you to make the Ubuntu "partiton" a bit small to be the OS used by default. Wubi should be used in my opinion as a fast, writeable Live CD, not as a real installation.

Also, remember that Wubi is not going to work anymore by default running in Ubuntu CDs, as Microsoft will force to the other PC companies to include UEFI, which is uncompatible.

In conclusion: use Wubi just for testing, not for real use. If you like Ubuntu after testing with Wubi, install it in your HD or in an USB drive.

Answer (score 1):

This site really works best one question at a time. But in this case, they're really very related so I guess it's ok.

While installing Windows, you don't have to make any room for Ubuntu at all – regardless of whether you're installing normally or using Wubi. Later, when you install Ubuntu, you'll have the option to decide how much goes to Ubuntu. In the case of a normal install, it'll automatically resize the Windows partition for you. You just use a slider to decide how much goes to Windows and how much goes to Ubuntu. In the case of Wubi, you select the size of the disk image.

At least by default, the Ubuntu installer uses a single file system for your Ubuntu system, including your home, so you don't have to choose that.

I wouldn't personally recommend using Wubi. The simple truth is that it's used by so few people, testing is quite poor and consequently, there are numerous issues with it. If, for some reason, you can't use the normal installer, it's fine, but if you can use the normal installer and install from a USB stick or CD/DVD, that's always preferable. The installation process is just as simple.

The big difference between a wubi install and a normal install, is that the wubi install doesn't use a partition on your harddisk, but instead stores everything in a disk image located on your Windows filesystem. This often causes some issues. For instance, in the case of a power outage, your disk image might get "lost", causing you to be unable to boot Ubuntu and you'll have to manually recover the file – this isn't straight forward.

So all in all, I'd recommend that you install Ubuntu using the normal installer and not Wubi. And if it's ok to wipe the entire disk while installing Windows, just tell the installer to use all available space. Later, when you install Ubuntu, you tell it how much space you want. Or you can just leave empty – unpartitioned – space while installing Windows and tell the Ubuntu installer to use free space. Either approach is fine, though the former is slightly faster.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to install windows on your system and dual boot with your current ubuntu installation, you don't have to re-install the ubuntu all-over again. You can chroot into your ubuntu installation after installing Windows on separate partition and booting from Ubuntu installation disk. There you just have to re-install the grub-loader to get your ubuntu back.

Find the detailed instructions at : 
http://meandmyubuntulinux.blogspot.com/2012/06/installing-windows-after-ubuntu-while.html

Hope this helps ....

Comment: Thank you very much, but I use Ubuntu from soon and I installed the previous version - 11.10, so I just upgraded to 12.04 and cannot compile the new kernel yet (I'm studiyng programing now and I'll try to compile the next kernel ;))
This is the reason why I want to reinstall the whole system !!!

Comment: @Samuil Alexandrov : hey... who told you that you have to compile the new kernel to install the grub-loader ??

Comment: recently I faced this problem when I installed Windows 8 Consumer preview in my laptop along side an upgraded Ubuntu 12.04 and later on removed it and re-installed Xp. I did exactly what I mentioned my blog-post.