# Ubuntu installation with single drive

Tags: partitioning

I have only one drive in my laptop with windows 7. Is it better to create another drive for installing Wubi? Will I have any disadvantages if I go ahead with installing in single drive? Which is the better way to install without any disadvantages?

Comment: By the way Im new to Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Installing **Ubuntu** via **WUBI** does not require another drive since **WUBI** will install Ubuntu inside Windows.

Read this posted question, as it is similar to yours, I think it might help you decide.

[wubi question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/155653/a-question-about-wubi)